# Show Countdown time on TextView Android

Tags: android, uitextview, countdowntimer

I want to countdown the time in my application and show the time on the screen with TextView. How to do it? 
I use  class CountDownTimer to countDown but if you have other solution please tell me and give some examples.
Sorry with my English and Thx.

Comment: I use CountDownTimer and it works great for me.  What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this code to calculate count down time and show to textview (This code count every second, you can change it)

```
int time=60; //second
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                time--;
                textview.setText("Countdown time: "+time+" seconds" );
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @QuocTruong answered, using `Handler` and `postDelayed` is the best option.

Take a look at [`CountDownAnimation`](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation/blob/master/src/com/ivanrf/countdownanimation/CountDownAnimation.java), it does exactly what you want. [Here](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation) is the project, which includes test files.